# HTML form data not posting to url but shows up in django model

Tags: python, django-models

brand new to django and webapps here.

I am experimenting with models and forms, and I have been able to successfully post data to my site using text fields and input buttons.

My hang is that my second form does not post anything and does not throw an error either.

I queried the class CustID and the set came back with all the data I had posted.

Here is the code and HTML:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Data Input</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Subscription Update</h1>
    <h2></h2>

    <form action="/addID/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="content"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
    </form>

    <form action="/getCust/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="cid"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Customer Look Up"/>
    </form>

    <ul>
        {% for SubID_item in all_items %}
            <li>{{ SubID_item.content }}
              <form action="/deleteID/{{SubID_item.id}}/"
                    style="display: inline;"
                    method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                  <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
              </form>
             </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Model:

```
    from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class SubID(models.Model):
   content = models.TextField()

class CustID(models.Model):
   cid = models.TextField()
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import SubID, CustID
import stripe
import json

# Create your views here.

def StrpFormView(request):
    all_subid_items = SubID.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'STRP_FORM.html',
    {'all_items':  all_subid_items})

def addID(request):
    new_item = SubID(content=request.POST['content'])
    new_item.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/STRP_Input/')

def getCust(request):
    new_item = CustID(cid=request.POST['cid'])
    new_item.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/STRP_Input/')

def deleteID(request, SubID_id):
    del_items = SubID.objects.get(id=SubID_id)
    del_items.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/STRP_Input/')

def basere(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/STRP_Input/')
```

urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from STRP_FORM.views import StrpFormView, addID, deleteID, getCust, basere


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('STRP_Input/', StrpFormView),
    path('addID/', addID),
    path('deleteID/<int:SubID_id>/', deleteID),
    path('getCust/', getCust),
    path('', basere),
]
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

NEW CODE:

```
def StrpFormView(request):
all_subid_items = SubID.objects.all()
all_custid_items = CustID.objects.all()
return render(request, 'STRP_FORM.html',
{'sub_items':  all_subid_items},
{'cust_items':  all_custid_items})

 <ul>
    {% for CustID_item in cust_item %}
       <li>{{ cust_item.cid }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: how do you know that it doesn't post? Did you used `print()` to see it?

Comment: I should say it does not show up on the site. I do not know if it posts. I am not sure how to test that.

Comment: do you get it from database when you display this page ? I see `getCust` redirects to `StrpFormView` which gets `SubID.objects.all()` but I don't see where you get `CustID` to display on page.

Comment: Yup it appears there is no view for the model CustID. Mind if I ask a follow up? What should I look at to understand the syntax for get both models to display?I have tried some things but its not intuitive to me yet.

Comment: you have to do the same as with SubID - get from database, send to template and use `for`-loop to display it. You don't need another view - do it in `StrpFormView`

Comment: @furas Alrighty I have added CustID to StrpFormView and I put the loop in the template. New code posted above

The site display the raw HTML tags now instead of the forms. Is it apparent to you why?

Comment: you have to display `CustID_item.cid`, not `cust_item.cid` - maybe it is problem.

Comment: OK! So it was that an 's' in for for loop for cust_item(s), and then the dictionaries need to be like this: ` {'sub_items':  all_subid_items, 'cust_items':  all_custid_items})`

and that did it. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Unrelated, but do yourself a favour and learn to use Django forms and named urls ;-)

Comment: Oh and yes : you certainly do NOT want to EVER delete anything on a GET request...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks for the advise! I am actually having an issue with the delete method right now. I have made three views to delete items from the three models I set up. The problem is now they are all directing to the same delete view. When I remove one delete form from the HTML the issue resolves. It seems I cannot have more than three forms that delete atm.